# Python quickstart.py adapted to my Google Sheets spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I implemented the Google Cloud API Client successfully using Python27 from 
here: 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?refresh=1

and ran the sample code, quickstart.py, ok.

I installed install --upgrade google-api-python-client.

I naively thought I could just change the spreadsheet IDs and the target range and it would work.  Wrong!

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
import argparse
flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly' 
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                     'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

    Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
    students in a sample spreadsheet:

    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ \ #continued next line
    1ksrW3mUJvPJkmv1HZyWC9Ma1Fbe1cX0CDegSjW2yIAY/edit
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                'version=v4')
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                          discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

    spreadsheetId = '1ksrW3mUJvPJkmv1HZyWC9Ma1Fbe1cX0CDegSjW2yIAY/edit#gid=0'
    rangeName = 'Class Data!B4:C9'
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
    print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            # Print columns B and C, which correspond to indices 2 and 3.
            print('%s, %s' % (row[1], row[2]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your script works. But one variable has to be modified.

#### From :

```
spreadsheetId = '1ksrW3mUJvPJkmv1HZyWC9Ma1Fbe1cX0CDegSjW2yIAY/edit#gid=0'
```

#### To :

```
spreadsheetId = '1ksrW3mUJvPJkmv1HZyWC9Ma1Fbe1cX0CDegSjW2yIAY'
```

#### Note :

Your spreadsheet ID is `1ksrW3mUJvPJkmv1HZyWC9Ma1Fbe1cX0CDegSjW2yIAY`. The detail information of Spreadsheet ID is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id).

If the script didn't work after you did above modification, feel free to tell me. At that time, please show us the error message.

### Edit :

The data from "B4:C9" is a list with 2 rows and 6 columns. The first index of list is 0. The reason of the error `main() Line 78 in main print('%s, %s' % (row[1], row[2])) IndexError: List index out of range` is this. So please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
print('%s, %s' % (row[1], row[2]))
```

#### To :

```
print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[1]))
```

Comment: I made the change and here is the response: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksrW3mUJvPJkmv1HZyWC9Ma1Fbe1cX0CDegSjW2yIAY)  Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot get to that link I put it here: [link] (http://www.atlantalearntodance.com/google-sheets.html)

Comment: This code actually runs without error message, but still does not pull in the data in the range B4:C9.

Comment: @Charles Cuthbert I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I saw your spreadsheet. I cannot find the sheet name of ``Class Data``. How about modifying the sheet name of ``rangeName = 'Class Data!B4:C9'``?

Comment: I removed the following:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
The code runs but does not return anyathing.
With that snippet in the error message is:
   Line 82 in <module>  main()
   Line 78 in main 
   print('%s, %s' % (row[1], row[2]))
IndexError: List index out of range

Comment: @Charles Cuthbert The first index of list is 0. So please modify ``print('%s, %s' % (row[1], row[2]))`` to ``print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[1]))``, and can you try again? If errors occur, can you show us your current script?

Comment: I made the change.  Error msg at: http://www.atlantalearntodance.com/google-sheets.html   Code at:http://www.atlantalearntodance.com/google-sheets-code.html Thanks!

Comment: @Charles Cuthbert Did your problems solved? If it is not yet, please tell me. I didn't know whether your problem was solved. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: It did not solve the problem. I made the change:  print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[1])). See error msg at: atlantalearntodance.com/google-sheets.html See code at:atlantalearntodance.com/google-sheets-code.html Your English is great!  Thanks!

Comment: @Charles Cuthbert I'm sorry for the inconvenience. When you chech the ``result `` from ``result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()`` using ``print(result)``, what is it displayed?

Comment: "result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadshee‌​tId, range=rangeName).execute()" using print(result) with my spreadsheet ID and range name returns: " 'result' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Charles Cuthbert I'm sorry I couldn't be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. Thanks to tanaike for his help. Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'sheets.googleapis.com-python-
quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

    Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
    students in a sample spreadsheet:

    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/insertSpreadSheetID/edit
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                'version=v4')
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                          discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

    spreadsheetId = 'spreadsheetId'
    rangeName = 'A1:B9'
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            # Print columns B and C, which correspond to indices 2 and 3.
            print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```